# Is there anyway to make my custom UI for incoming and outgoing calls in Android?

Tags: android, system-calls, telephonymanager, android-phone-call

I want to develop an app from which user should be able to make a call But I don't want to trigger system phone app to make a call. I would rather like to have my own UI for outgoing calls and also for incoming calls. That being said, I want my app user to use my phone for all incoming and outgoing calls and this should happen only when my app is in focus.

It should work with default phone app when the app isn't running. Is there any way to do it?

I went through below links but not able to figure out the solution. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[Build a calling app - Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/selfManaged#connectionImplementation)

[Telephone framework - Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/)

[Create a phone replacement app - Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/telecom/#replacePhoneApp)

[InCallService - Requires to make app default phone app - Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/InCallService)

Comment: Why downvote question without explanation?

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't a supported use-case with the existing APIs.  If your app wants to handle calls, it needs to be the default dialer app.